# Why do some of the pytube streams resolutions appear as "None"?

Tags: python, pytube

I was wondering why some of the resolutions in pytube streams -especially the mp4 ones- appear as "None"?

```
yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXb3EKWsInQ")
for stream in yt.streams.filter(adaptive=True):
    print(stream)
```

Output:

```
<Stream: itag="315" mime_type="video/webm" res="2160p" fps="60fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="337" mime_type="video/webm" res="2160p" fps="60fps" vcodec="vp9.2" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="401" mime_type="video/mp4" res="2160p" fps="60fps" vcodec="av01.0.13M.10.0.110.09.16.09.0" progressive="False" 
type="video">
<Stream: itag="701" mime_type="video/mp4" res="None" fps="60fps" vcodec="av01.0.13M.10.0.110.09.16.09.0" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="308" mime_type="video/webm" res="1440p" fps="60fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="336" mime_type="video/webm" res="1440p" fps="60fps" vcodec="vp9.2" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="400" mime_type="video/mp4" res="1440p" fps="60fps" vcodec="av01.0.12M.10.0.110.09.16.09.0" progressive="False" 
type="video">
<Stream: itag="700" mime_type="video/mp4" res="None" fps="60fps" vcodec="av01.0.12M.10.0.110.09.16.09.0" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="299" mime_type="video/mp4" res="1080p" fps="60fps" vcodec="avc1.64002a" progressive="False" type="video">      
<Stream: itag="303" mime_type="video/webm" res="1080p" fps="60fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="335" mime_type="video/webm" res="1080p" fps="60fps" vcodec="vp9.2" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="399" mime_type="video/mp4" res="1080p" fps="60fps" vcodec="av01.0.09M.10.0.110.09.16.09.0" progressive="False" 
type="video">
<Stream: itag="699" mime_type="video/mp4" res="None" fps="60fps" vcodec="av01.0.09M.10.0.110.09.16.09.0" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="298" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="60fps" vcodec="avc1.4d4020" progressive="False" type="video">       
<Stream: itag="302" mime_type="video/webm" res="720p" fps="60fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="334" mime_type="video/webm" res="720p" fps="60fps" vcodec="vp9.2" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="398" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="60fps" vcodec="av01.0.08M.10.0.110.09.16.09.0" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="698" mime_type="video/mp4" res="None" fps="60fps" vcodec="av01.0.08M.10.0.110.09.16.09.0" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="135" mime_type="video/mp4" res="480p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.4d401f" progressive="False" type="video">       
<Stream: itag="244" mime_type="video/webm" res="480p" fps="30fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="333" mime_type="video/webm" res="480p" fps="60fps" vcodec="vp9.2" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="397" mime_type="video/mp4" res="480p" fps="30fps" vcodec="av01.0.04M.10.0.110.09.16.09.0" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="697" mime_type="video/mp4" res="None" fps="60fps" vcodec="av01.0.05M.10.0.110.09.16.09.0" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="134" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.4d401e" progressive="False" type="video">       
<Stream: itag="243" mime_type="video/webm" res="360p" fps="30fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="332" mime_type="video/webm" res="360p" fps="60fps" vcodec="vp9.2" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="396" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="30fps" vcodec="av01.0.01M.10.0.110.09.16.09.0" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="696" mime_type="video/mp4" res="None" fps="60fps" vcodec="av01.0.04M.10.0.110.09.16.09.0" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="133" mime_type="video/mp4" res="240p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.4d4015" progressive="False" type="video">       
<Stream: itag="242" mime_type="video/webm" res="240p" fps="30fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="331" mime_type="video/webm" res="240p" fps="60fps" vcodec="vp9.2" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="395" mime_type="video/mp4" res="240p" fps="30fps" vcodec="av01.0.00M.10.0.110.09.16.09.0" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="695" mime_type="video/mp4" res="None" fps="60fps" vcodec="av01.0.01M.10.0.110.09.16.09.0" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="160" mime_type="video/mp4" res="144p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.4d400c" progressive="False" type="video">       
<Stream: itag="278" mime_type="video/webm" res="144p" fps="30fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="330" mime_type="video/webm" res="144p" fps="60fps" vcodec="vp9.2" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="394" mime_type="video/mp4" res="144p" fps="30fps" vcodec="av01.0.00M.10.0.110.09.16.09.0" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="694" mime_type="video/mp4" res="None" fps="60fps" vcodec="av01.0.00M.10.0.110.09.16.09.0" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="139" mime_type="audio/mp4" abr="48kbps" acodec="mp4a.40.5" progressive="False" type="audio">
<Stream: itag="140" mime_type="audio/mp4" abr="128kbps" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="False" type="audio">
<Stream: itag="249" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="50kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">
<Stream: itag="250" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="70kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">
<Stream: itag="251" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="160kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">
```

I downloaded the itag=700 one by using get_by_itag. It appears as 1440p and plays smoothly. I have no idea why its res in the streams is "None".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, [itags.py](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/blob/84faec34c8a66f502ac635a5610445dbff160654/pytube/itags.py), which does the mapping of itags to resolution and bitrates, was last updated in April 2021. I would assume, the itags which list None as resolution did not exist yet then. You can update the file yourself, test it and then send a pull request to the package maintainer to include those newer itag values.